# How can I send multiple data via one object flow in cameo and access it in an opaque action/decision

Tags: javascript, modeling, sysml, uaf

I am currently working on a cameo model, trying to make it executable.
For this we need a data exchange from action to action and interaction with that data.

You can imagine it like this:
The user inputs values
"Mission 1"
100
"Task 1"
Depending on those values, there should be decisions made in the execution and those values should be changed. I imagined doing it using decisions and opaque actions. Unfortunately it turns out that it's harder than expected.

Here's my approaches:

1. I created a datatype that includes a String (this property is called P1) and an Integer (this property is called P2) and then created an instance of it:
   [Datatype and Instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25QQH.png)
   Then I tried to access one of those two values by setting up an opaque action with an input called "input" and the body as "x = input.P1". "x" is the name of the output of the opaque action. Like this, I just wanted to seperate P1 from the data:
   [Diagram with instance and opaque action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhtQJ.png)
   This didn't work, as an Undefined object is the result i end up with.
2. I thought, well, using a datatype might be better but i can find a workaround and tried to define an array as the output of an opaque action and access it in another opaque action. I figured out that if i do it like "result = ["Test",1]" The opaque action will just send "Test" and in the next iteration send 1, but not at the same time as an array as i wished. Then I thought, well, not too bad, let's just make a decision that checks if the value is a String, like this we can seperate the data as well, but turns out the "Test" will not be sent as a string and my setup doesnt work either:
   [This approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8kox.png)
3. Then i tried something else, here an NativeArray Object is sent, but then when i try to access it via "x = input[0]" the result is "o", as this is the first letter of the name of the object starting with "org.javascript....":
   [Third approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWHbY.png)

I could not find any way to get what I want and therefore hope that someone can help me with my issue as I can not imagine that what I want is not possible at all. I use Cameo Systems Modeler 2021x and UAF Architecture.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @OyinladeDemola, there is no more code to provide as it is a Model, not a script. All information provided is in the images linked.